# How can I remove border-bottom of last div' separator through CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am showing latest news in a div box in which each news is separated from others by a separator of border-bottom. Note that in the HTML I am not using any ul li; rather than I am using simply divs. The problem is that the last news div is also showing the border bottom separator. I dont know how to remove it even I have already tried :last-child selector but it's not working. I know by using ul li, the problem can be solved by :last-child, but I dont want to change my HTML. Here is a snaphost:

[image: Image Link]

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="float_left_div posts">
    <h3>Latest News</h3>
    <div class="news_wrapper">
        <div class="news_txt">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. <span>more+</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="div_separator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="news_wrapper">
        <div class="news_txt">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. <span>more+</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="div_separator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="news_wrapper">
        <div class="news_txt">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. <span>more+</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="div_separator"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The demo is at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE6Re/3/)

So by keeping the same HTML, how can we remove the last border of separtor?

Comment: @Harry, you used `.posts .news_wrapper
{
 padding:-1px 15px;
}` which not correct. We cant use -ve padding like -ve margin.

Comment: Which is why I said it was a hack mate. Not supposed to do but works. Anyway, you have said you are ok with `last-child` so I guess that solves it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use CSS `last-child` property to remove the border.

```
.posts .news_wrapper:last-child .div_separator
{
border-bottom:0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LE6Re/8/)

Comment: This answer works and only requires for the CSS to be modified.

Comment: @Harry i didn't modify any HTML

Comment: @Harry, i never said i dont want to use `:last-child`; rather than i said i dont want to use ul li. I want to get solution by keeping the same HTML. Can you please reread my question?

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the the :last-child pseudo-class does not work in most browsers. If i where you i would put the border to the top (instead of bottom) and then use

```
.posts .news_wrapper:first-child .div_separator{border-top:0px;}
```

Please note first:child is recognised in most browsers.

Comment: what do you mean by "most browsers?"

Comment: Mainly IE. last-child is supported in IE9 + and first-child is supported in IE7 +.

Comment: If it doesnt work there must be conflicting styles somewhere, if you could send a link to the page or use js fiddle then i'm happy to look at it. If you've used last-child your probably going to face problems in everything below IE9